# How to have <picture> elements with different links on each image?

Tags: javascript, html

Time ago I had a header implemented with a Bootstrap carousel: You know, something like this:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src="pic1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="example.com"><img src="pic2.jpg"></a></div>
</div>
```

Pay attention to that link on "pic2.jpg", this will be fun...

Recently, I have been asked to use `<picture>` elements, so now it is posible to display images for mobile devices:

```
<div class="item">
    <picture>
        <source media="(max-width: 576px)" srcset="pic1-small.jpg">
        <img src="pic1.jpg">
     </picture>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <picture>
        <source media="(max-width: 576px)" srcset="pic2-small.jpg">
        <img src="pic2.jpg">
     </picture>
</div>
```

And here is the tricky question: I need to add a link only in the mobile image (pic2-small.jpg).

(Well, in fact could be links on every image, or none at all, only in the mobile image, only in the desktop image... This is managed by the administrator user)

So, I can't do this because the link should be only for pic2-small, not pic2:

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="example.com">
        <picture>
            <source media="(max-width: 576px)" srcset="pic2-small.jpg">
            <img src="pic2.jpg">
         </picture>
    </a>
</div>
```

What I did is this:

```
<div class="item" onclick="header_onclick(this)">
    <picture>
        <source media="(max-width: 576px)" srcset="pic2-small.jpg?target=pic2-small-link">
        <img src="pic2.jpg">
     </picture>
     <a id="pic2-small-link" href="example.com" style="display: none"></a>
</div>

<script>
function header_onclick(carousel_item)
{
    var current_src = carousel_item.querySelector("img").currentSrc;                
    if (typeof current_src === "undefined") {
        return;
    }

    var src_parts = current_src.split("?target=");                
    if (src_parts.length < 2) {
        return;
    }
            
    var link = document.getElementById(src_parts[1]);                
    if (link) {
        link.click();
    }
}
</script>
```

- An `onclick` event in the carousel item and a javascript function.
- A `target` value in the URL of the image.
- A hidden `<a>` with the destination URL.

The magic is in this line:

```
var current_src = carousel_item.querySelector("img").currentSrc;
```

`currentSrc` has the URL of the image that the browser is currently showing according to the screen size. So, from that URL I take the `target` parameter and use it to get the corresponding link and then execute it.

All this is working, but I feel it too hacky for my taste. I'm not very experienced with the `<picture>` element, so my question is: this could be resolved in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes hacky!

This is very hacky as you are doing a media query the long way. Interpreting the resulting media aware DOM for a URL that you then manually parse.

#### Learn and use the API

There are many API's available to a modern browser environment. The general rule is if it can be done on the page via HTML/CSS there is an API that can do it in JavaScript.

I never use media queries as I serve to interrogated devices so I am not 100% up on media querie API's, but for static pages you can use [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

#### Setting up media dependent links.

There are many ways to setup your page. But in code you can access media queries using [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) which returns the result of a media query as [MediaQueryList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList)

You can access an elements media attribute by name. for example if an image is clicked in your example HTML `event.target.parentElement.querySelector("source").media`

You can store the different links as data attributes.

I think the best approach is to pre-process the markup when it has loaded and just set the link references depending on the associated media query.

### Example

The code checks each link (anchor element) for a source element and uses the source elements media attribute to do a media query.

Depending on the result of the media query it gets the appropriate data set item and set the link `href` property.

Each picture has a different media query. Hover to see link href (I have set title to show the link as example)

```js
// do in page onload event
for (const link of linkedImages.querySelectorAll("a")) {
    const source = link.querySelector("source");
    if (source) {
        const isSmall = matchMedia(source.media).matches;
        link.href = isSmall ? link.dataset.linkSmall : link.dataset.linkNormal;
        link.title = link.href; // just for example 
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="item" id = "linkedImages">
    <a data-link-small="smallLink.com" data-link-normal="normalLink.com">
        <picture>
            <source media="(max-width:  1700px)" srcset="https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7qq2.png?s=48&g=1">
            <img class="images" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7qq2.png?s=328&g=1">
        </picture>
    </a><br>
    <a data-link-small="smallLink.com" data-link-normal="normalLink.com">
        <picture>
            <source media="(max-width:  500px)" srcset="https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7qq2.png?s=48&g=1">
            <img class="images" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7qq2.png?s=328&g=1" width="128">
         </picture>    
     </a>
</div>
```

Comment: By _interrogated devices_ did you mean _integrated devices_? Apparently [_Device Interrogation_](https://www.acc.org/~/media/Non-Clinical/Files-PDFs-Excel-MS-Word-etc/Meetings/2016/Course%20PDFs/Core%20Curriculum/Fri%20Post/Fri%207%2030%20am%20Obias%20Manno.pdf?la=en) is a concept for devices like pacemakers...

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I meant interrogated as a substitute for device discovery on a landing page.

Comment: This looks more like the kind of code I want! I wasn't aware of matchMedia(), I will investigate further and I will give it a try later, but at least now I have a path to follow. Thanks!